# Eigen::aligned_allocator fails with std::unordered_multimap

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I am trying to compile this code in XCode 6:

```
std::unordered_multimap< Frame*, Sim3, std::hash<Frame*>, std::equal_to<Frame*>, Eigen::aligned_allocator< std::pair<const Frame*,Sim3> > > trackingFailed;
```

It fails with:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/unordered_map:1461:5: Static_assert failed "Invalid allocator::value_type"
```

Is it still necessary to use `aligned_allocator` in Eigen 3.2.2? Why is it failing with C++11/C++14 and libc++?

**EDIT**:

I get `no type named value_type` if I remove the Eigen allocator from the `unordered_map` template declaration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the mistake is that the pointer should be `const`, not the pointee. 
I.e. try `Eigen::aligned_allocator< std::pair<Frame* const, Sim3> >` as the allocator type.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The error was totally misleading. This is not my code and it was used in other projects, don't understand how it compiled for them? Maybe the GNU compiler is less strict?

Comment: @aledalgrande Perhaps libstdc++ does not `static_assert` that the value type of the allocator must be the same as the value type of the container.

Comment: I see. It seems Clang/libc++ are not forgiving about C++11 constructs (from my little experience).

Comment: @Columbo, right, libstdc++ allows e.g. `vector<int, allocator<char>>` and it rebinds the allocator to the correct type. I hate this extension, I would like to deprecate it!

Comment: Found another one: `std::vector< KFConstraintStruct*, Eigen::aligned_allocator<FramePoseStruct*> >` I really don't know how it compiled that, these two structs are completely separate.

Comment: @aledalgrande, read my comment above. Libstdc++ ignores the exact type of the allocator and rebinds it to the container's value type.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21770

Comment: Oh it ignores it *completely*. Wow.