# Unordered_map declaration throws error with NDK (clang), works fine with gcc

Tags: android, c++, clang, unordered-map

I'm trying to run a C++ project on Android. The following statement appears in one of the source files (part of a big project).

```
std::unordered_map  <int, std::shared_ptr<Frame>, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>,
    Eigen::aligned_allocator< std::pair<const int, std::shared_ptr<Frame> > > > idToKeyFrame;
```

The NDK build complains the following

```
sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/unordered_map:1684:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'is_same<value_type, typename allocator_type::value_type>::value' "Invalid allocator::value_type"
```

I cannot spot what part of declaration is incompatible. Please help in fixing this error.

[cplusplus.com reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/)

### Update

When I modify the allocator (as suggested in comment by Marc) to   `Eigen::aligned_allocator<std::pair<int, std::shared_ptr<Frame>>>` The error message remains the same but line number changes

```
sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/unordered_map:854:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'is_same<value_type, typename allocator_type::value_type>::value' "Invalid allocator::value_type"
```

### Update++

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336941/eigenaligned-allocator-fails-with-stdunordered-multimap) :

> libstdc++ does not static_assert, libstdc++ ignores the exact type of the allocator and rebinds it to the container's value type.

and

> Clang/libc++ are not forgiving

### Yet another Update

I have been able to go past the error by commenting out the line in the source for `unordered_map`. This is a resort for now (until I get a solution).

Comment: try changing `std::pair<const int,` to `std::pair<int,`

Comment: @MarcStröbel Kindly see the update. I get the same error message but on a different line.